# What is the answer to this list?

Tags: list, f#

```
3::[4;5;2;7];;
List.length [4;5;2;7];;
[4;5;2;7]::3;;
```

This gives the error This expression was expected to have type int list list but here has type int

I know that it can be solved by doing : `[4;5;2;7];; List.append it [3];;` but is there any other way to do it?

Comment: "This gives an error" without more information is never a good sign on a question. You've got the error message - why haven't you included it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really bad question. However, The last line in your code will fail with

> This expression was expected to have type
>       int list list     but here has type
>       int

.. because :: concatenates an element to a list. It can only do it from the front because the list is a singly linked list. If you want to add an element at the end of the list, you're probably using the wrong data structure. If you really want to add an element to the end of a list, you could do

```
[4;5;2;7] @ [3];;
```

Be aware that this will be really inefficient.